# laravel backup raising 404 to return a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In short what is happening is, when I try to access a route, Laravel shows a 404 error, with a short description "**Page not Found, No query results for model [App\Models\Product] teste** ".

Inside of my model I have the method "teste" which invokes a route.

```
    public function teste($crud = false)
    {
        return '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" href="product/teste" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Just a demo custom button."><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Add Item</a>';
    }
```

[button image in the datatable line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4bdc.png)

Adding a button inside of ProductCrudController

```
$this->crud->addButton('top', 'bteste', 'model_function', 'teste', 'beginning');
```

Inside of custom.php I have tried already:

```
CRUD::resource('product/teste', 'ProductCrudController@teste');
Route::get('product/teste', 'ProductCrudController@teste');
```

Inside of my Controller I have my method named teste

```
public function teste(){
    return view('vendor/backpack/crud/teste');
}
```

And finally inside of this path I have my view "which is pretty simple" and only retues a simple hello.

**What is the purpose**

I need to build a form which allows the user to add "a component" for the product once that the product is always customized. This means, a combination of components makes up a new product. 
What I need is: Add a new button in the product line which when clicked gonna redirect the user to add all components which makes up this product. Same idea of an order which contain items.

I could not find by myself the possible options to fit my need.
Is that possible to be done by backpack? If so is there any example to be followed?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much I can do to help - try to debug with ```dd('got here')``` from the route, down to the controller, then the model, to see what file this error comes from.

Comment: The steps you've taken are correct, but if you're trying to add a button to each product, you should add the button to the "line" stack (not "top"), change your route to ```product/{id}/teste``` and add ```$id``` as parameter to your Controller method.